# how to run to foreach loops for single select tag laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show previously selected options as selected, I have two data sets.

1. blocks that are JSON encoded in a column with country codes.
2. countries list from the country table

I want to compare both and want to show countries selected that are present in users blocked colmn JSON encoded

```
 $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
    $blocks = json_decode($user->blocked);
    @foreach(  Countries::orderBy('country_name')->get() as $country )
     <option  value="{{$country->country_code}}"  >{{ $country->country_name }}</option>
    @endforeach

i tried following but it selects on 1 value either 1st or last

 @foreach ($sundaysArray as $key => $value)

               
 @foreach(  Countries::orderBy('country_name')->get() as $country )
                    
<option @if( $value == $country->country_code ) selected="selected" @endif value="{{$country->country_code}}"  >{{ $country->country_name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endforeach
```

Comment: Why the 2 foreach loops, use `in_array()` instead. The 2 foreach loops will add the options multiple times. side note: Try to keep the queries in the controller, where they belong. you are getting the countries from the db every loop iteration.

Comment: yes sir but i want to show contries = selected should be already selected

Comment: you can use in_array for that, as I commented

Comment: sir can you post in answer please i am not getting clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gert-b

```
$user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
$sundaysArray = json_decode($user->blocked);
@foreach(  Countries::orderBy('country_name')->get() as $country )
<option @if (in_array($country->country_code,$sundaysArray)) selected="selected" @endif value="{{$country->country_code}}"  >{{ $country->country_name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$selected = explode(",", $products->supplier_id);

<select  name="supplier_id[]" multiple="multiple">
   @foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
     <option value="{{ $supplier->id }}" {{ (in_array($supplier->id, $selected)) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $supplier->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Please always explain your answer an put code in a code block.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).